How to find period of an arbitrary periodic function?
Is there any known algorithm to find the period of a generic function which is known to be periodic?
The most direct approach would be to solve for $T$ the functional equation $$f(x+T)=f(x)$$ which is obviously a hard problem . Just like there's no known algorithm to find antiderivative of integrals, apart from complicated symbolic manipulation algorithms which are still not guaranteed to succeed, similarly, there might be no algorithm to find out periods of arbitrary functions. Is that the case or has there been any work along this direction? Is there any answer if we put some strong constraints on the functions such as analyticity or "whatever" is required E.g. You can't derive the definition of Gamma function by requiring it to be an extension of the factorial to real numbers, but once you introduce log-convexity you get the definition of gamma function. So, I am happy if somebody can give an algorithm for not an arbitrary function but for function "with some suitable conditions", where the suitable conditions are upto the answerer. This might seem like a not so well defined question with lack of clarity and a bit open-ended and I acknowledge that. But this is precisely what I am requesting here: if this is too vast or too abstract a problem to solve, modify this problem to a similar one which is solvable.
I came across this question which gives a numerical answer, but I am looking for an analytical one. Indeed, the simplest thing must be to just plot the function and "see" that it is periodic: the bottleneck being, this works only for small periods.
Again, I might not be using the correct language to frame the question, but hopefully it is clear what I am looking for...
EDIT (after getting close votes)
As I clarified above and also in the comments, if this is too abstract or unclear, I am directly asking the answerer to state whether a generic procedure to find period of a large class of periodic function or not. In loose words, if the answer is "Nothing can be said", then my request is "When can something be said, and what can be said?". Like obviously I can find out periods of $A f_1 +b f_2$ with $f_1$ and $f_2$ periodic. How can I generalise this to more arbitrary combinations? This is an open-ended question, which is why I am giving full freedom to the answerer to restrict the class of functions he considers.

You are asking for the moon, I think!

There is nothing whatsoever that can be said about this without more information about how you are given the function $f$. Do you have numerical data? Do you have an expression of $f$ in terms of other more familiar functions? What kind of expression and what kind of functions?

(Here are the kinds of examples you have to rule out by getting more specific about how you are given $f$: consider the function $f$ which is equal to $\sin x$ if the Riemann hypothesis is true and $0$ if it's false. What is its period...?)

I feared that this kind of thing might come up, which is why I wrote the last para: how can I make this problem well-defined but still "generic enough"? I know typical methods like finding the lcm of periods of periodic functions like those discussed here, so I am hoping for more generic scenarios...

@QiaochuYuan I cannot differentiate such a function, but there are quite well defined procedures of differentiating a function using "standard results" for differentiation of known functions like trig functions, monomials, exponentials and their inverses, etc. Similarly, I am looking for a procedure for a "suitably large" class of functions, where the exact meaning of "suitably large" is left to the answerer.

Remark: having access to a function's values on some bounded interval $[-M,M]$ will never be enough to identify a function's period (because even if it looks like it has a small period, maybe that pattern doesn't hold forever).

@GregMartin Yes, I am aware of this and pointed this out in my question in other words in the 2nd last para.

Duplicate but unanswered question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687856/

Constant functions would prove problematic for any such method.
